# How to construct a LATERAL JOIN in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table `tb` like this:

```
    db=# SELECT * FROM tb ORDER by id;
 id |  name  | luckynumber 
----+--------+-------------
  1 | Alice  |         100
  2 | Bob    |         300
  3 | Chad   |          13
  4 | Dave   |         123
  5 | Eve    |         130
  6 | Faythe |         777
(6 rows)
```

An SQL below returns modulo of each person`s luckynumber to Chad's lucky number:

```
    db=# SELECT name, mod(a.luckynumber, b.luckynumber) as modulo FROM tb AS a, 
    LATERAL (SELECT id, luckynumber FROM tb WHERE name = 'Chad') AS b 
    WHERE a.id <> b.id ORDER by modulo;
```

```
  name  | modulo 
--------+--------
 Eve    |      0
 Bob    |      1
 Dave   |      6
 Alice  |      9
 Faythe |     10
(5 rows)
```

What is a SQLAlchemy equivalent of this SQL ? Thank you!

Comment: The lateral is unnecessary. This can be written as a regular cross join which every ORM should be able to understand: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=839188b889f058d068cff1c41dd52294

Comment: [Docs for SQLAlchemy lateral join syntax](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html?highlight=lateral#lateral-correlation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In complement as a_horse_with_no_name... Or with a simple join...

```
select a.name, mod(a.luckynumber, b.luckynumber) as modulo 
FROM   tb AS a  
       join tb as b ON a.id <> b.id 
where  b.name = 'Chad'
ORDER  by modulo;
```